# Awk script returns "Bad Interpreter" error

Tags: scripts, awk

I have written a simple `awk` script that I learned to write using a PDF tutorial.  When I run this script, I get an error that says `Bad Interpreter`, along with the first line of the script.

So what's wrong with this line:

```
#!/bin/awk
```

Comment: Running command: `whereis awk` will tell you the correct path!

Comment: @konrad or `which awk`

Answer (score 2):

The line is not complete and points to the wrong directory, it should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
```

Thats called the 'magic-line' or 'shebang' and tells the shell what program is needed to interpret the script.

An other way to run `awk` is (pointed out by [@Knud larsen](https://askubuntu.com/users/475620/knud-larsen)):

```
awk -f file.awk [file to be processed]
```

Comment: The safe way to run an awk script is (AFAIK) : `awk -f file.awk  [file to be processed]` ... Besides that, I have never seen an awk script starting with `#!/usr/bin/awk`

Comment: I've fixed the problems with my first awk script, thanks to you two.

Comment: Then you might want to click the check-mark beside the answer to mark your problem solved.